# Constructor Call Within Different Constructor Yields Erroneous Data

Tags: c++, constructor

The following is the smallest program that replicates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        _a = 0;
    }
    Test(int t)
    {
        Test();
        _b = t;
    }
    void Display()
    {
        cout << _a << ' ' << _b << endl;
    }
private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
};

int main()
{
    Test test(10);
    test.Display(); // 70 10

    return 0;
}
```

When I do this, `_a` is initialized with garbage. Why does this happen? Is there a problem when a constructor is invoked from within another?

Comment: Note: remember than constructors that can be called with a single argument are better declared `explicit` to avoid surprising conversions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is in this code:

```
Test(int t)
{
    Test();
    _b = t;
}
```

This does **not** call the default `Test` constructor, then set `_b = t`.  Instead, it creates a temporary object of type `Test` using the default constructor, ignores that temporary object, then sets `_b = t`.  Consequently, the default constructor won't run for the receiver object, so `_a` will remain uninitialized.

To fix this, in C++11, you can write

```
Test(int t) : Test() {
    _b = t;
}
```

which does call the default constructor, or (in C++03) you can factor out the initialization code from the default constructor into a helper member function that you call from both the default and parameterized constructor:

```
Test() {
    defaultInit();
}
Test(int t) {
    defaultInit();
    _b = t;
}
```

Or, if you have a C++11 compiler, just eliminate the default constructor by using default initializers, like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(int t)
    {
        _b = t;
    }
    void Display()
    {
        cout << _a << ' '<< _b << endl;
    }
private:
    int _a = 0;
    int _b;
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the default initializers syntax, much more concise than other alternatives.